# FFImageLoading Xamarin Disk Cache Not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

No matter what I try, I cannot get FFImageLoading disk caching to work in my Xamarin Forms app. I have FadeAnimationEnabled turned on, with a long duration, so that I can easily see when images are cached vs not.

In memory caching is working great, no long fade-in on the second load.

But relaunch the app, and I see the long fade, no caching.

Turn off WiFi, and then no images at all.

- I have tried CacheType as both All and Disk
- I have CacheDuration set to 30 days
- I call both Init() and InitImageSourceHandler() after XF.Init() in AppDelegate (and equivalent on Android)
- Images are loaded from remote URL (Google Storage HTTPS)
- I use MonkeyCache for other local disk caching with no problems

Configuration:

- Both iOS and Android
- FFImageLoading 2.4.11
- XF 4.7.0

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I am still stuck on this, getting absolutely no disk caching with FFImageLoading.